# Custom sound effect variable must be defined as a property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I created a custom class to handle sound effects in my app. While implementing the code, it didn't work at all as a local variable. I defined it as a property, and it worked just fine. Is there a way for me to be able to just use a local variable when using the class?

SoundEffect.h

```
@interface SoundEffect : NSObject

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)soundName;
- (void)play;
- (void)pause;

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *soundName;

@end
```

SoundEffect.m

```
@implementation SoundEffect

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)soundName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.soundName = soundName;
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], self.soundName]];
    NSError *error;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (self.player == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}

- (void)play {
    [self.player play];
}

- (void)pause {
    [self.player pause];
}

@end
```

Implementation

```
self.effect = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithSoundNamed:@"laserShot"];
[self.effect play];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate, but as far as I can tell, there's no way around this. Under ARC, the local variable is released when the method returns, and your player is destroyed before the sound has a chance to play. You have to declare the player as a property in order to keep a reference to the player alive.